# Set TextArea background color from Color Picker

Tags: javafx, textarea

I want to change the background color of the TextArea to the current color selected in ColorPicker. The problem is, TextArea has some depth and I can't directly change the background color of it through normal code.

How would I go about binding the background color of the textarea to the current color in colorpicker?

P.S. 
I know how to 'manually' change the background color of a TextArea through CSS. I want to do it through normal code.
Here is how it works in CSS;

```
.text-area .content {
    -fx-background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using setStyle?

Comment: Doesn't work with TextArea because you can't directly change the background color of a text area. You have to change the background color of the content of textarea, which is not accessible through textarea.getContent() since that method does not exist.

Comment: How did you change it in css?

Comment: I edited the thread accordingly.

Comment: I am guessing it's similar to changing the color of a textfield. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27700006/how-do-you-change-the-background-color-of-a-textfield-without-changing-the-borde

Comment: Here for textarea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31823715/how-to-change-textarea-background-color-more-than-once

Comment: The one for textfield works splendidly! Thanks, you can turn that comment into an answer now ^^